# How can I prevent home elements from rendering on every page?

Tags: reactjs

In my home class I have a  Hello, every time I change tabs, the Hello always gets rendered. How can I prevent this? I did not include any  field of Hello in other tabs, this is quite weird.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h3>Hello</h3>
    )
  }
}
```

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,} from 'react-router-dom'

import NotFound from './components/App/NotFound';

import Home from './components/Home/Home';

import Navbar from "./components/NavBar/Navbar";
import Login from "./components/Login/Login";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp/SignUp";

function App() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Navbar /> 
          <br/> 
            <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
  
export default App;
```

Image of the react app,
[image: the image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey u may wanna do this,

```
<Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
```

the path `/` actually matches everything on the site, to prevent this you can use,

#### 1: [`exact` prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route)

```
<Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
<Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
```

#### 2: [`Switch` component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
  <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
</Switch>
```

Only one `Route` will be used. NOTE: You have to keep the order maintained

Comment: @user13883454 ur welcome :) , please, do not forget to mark as answer & upvote

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is that you render all your routes together. You should either pass the `exact` prop inside the Route component for each Route

```
 <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
```

or render your routes inside the `Switch` tag.

```
  <Switch>
     <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
     <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
     <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
</Switch>
```

Remember that the order of your routes is also important and you may want to render your root route at the end. For the latter, don't forget to import `Switch` from react-router-dom